# The cookie expiration time is not valid

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have a problem with my 1 computer so I copy my project to other computer (Windows but this project was created on Linux) and I have a problem. I have a few errors. First is like in a title

> The cookie expiration time is not valid.
>   I see that when I visit this controller

```
if($lang == 'pl' || $lang == 'en'){
        $this->checkLanguage($lang);
        $route = $lang . '.articles';
        return redirect()->route($route);
    } else {
        Session::flash('error', 'This language is\'t available');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

When I visit articles I can see

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `stats` where `token` is null)

I suppose that the second problem is method to save visitors in MySQL.

```
$token = time() . rand(1, 999);
    if(!Cookie::get('visitors')){
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('visitors', $token), true, 1440);
    }
    $stats = stats::where('token', Cookie::get('visitors'))->count();
    if(Cookie::get('lang')){
        $lang = Cookie::get('lang');
    } else {
        $lang = 'en';
    }
    if($stats == 0){
        stats::create([
            'token' => $token,
            'lang' => $lang
        ]);
    }
    return $next($request);
```

Could you help me? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be php 32 bit problem , [check this out](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15488)

Edit: I had this problem solved, I commented my [fix](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte/issues/259#issuecomment-452544138) on Goutte's github repo issues section

Answer (score 0):

Check the *SESSION_LIFETIME* in your .env file, leave that field empty, that solve my problem